# Angular pipe, custom decimal numbers

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-angular-ui

having

```
let myNumber = Math.PI;
let myPrecision = 4;
```

How can I display `myNumber` using `myPrecision`?

```
<label> {{ myNumber | ???myPrecision }} </label>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe please check that

Comment: `decimalPipe.transform(this.myNumber,"1.2-2")` The digit info can be x.0-0. (x is minimum number of digits before decimal) [Usage notes](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#usage-notes)

Comment: please read attentively and please answer how to use `myPrecision` param, not hardcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One not really elegant, but solution, could be

```
<div> {{ myNumber | number: '1.' + myPrecision + '-' + myPrecision + }} </div>
```

**PS.**
After the Joosep's [suggestion](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipes-r31sby?file=app%2Fapp.component.html), I made a custom pipe, like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'precision' })
export class PrecisionPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, precision: number): string {
    return value.toFixed(precision);
  }
}
```

so now I can use

```
<div> {{ myNumber | precision: myPrecision }} </div>
```

Comment: I mean it works, you could also just make your own pipe

Comment: I made a custom pipe as an example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipes-r31sby?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Joosep.P great work, would you like to post it like an answer? (think is not possible now...)

Comment: I can no longer post an answer as this question is closed. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Joosep.P, you could use `myNumber.ToFixed(myPrecision)` without need to Pow etc

Comment: @Joosep.P I updated the answer with the custom pipe code